# How to Measure Double Handle Push out Windows?

Tags: windows, measuring, screens

I want to buy some screens but I need them custom made. I need to measure them but not sure how to measure them properly.

The screen would look like this

http://www.southcoastscreens.com/double-handle-push-out-window.html

my window would look something like this(not my window, but simliar)

[image]

Comment: Have you asked the custom screen shop what measurements they need?

Comment: Yes, they said there is too many different styles and they can't tell me how to properly measure. They will build whatever measurements I need to bring. The other custom shops that would measure require a 6 window minimum but I only need 2.